# Regarding a specific Turán number of graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I wish to know the latest bound on the number of edges a graph of girth greater than or equal to $t$ can have.

Specifically, I heard somewhere that a graph of girth greater than or equal to $t$ can have $O(n^{2-\frac{2}{t}})$ edges. Is it true?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There’s something weird about your guess here: increasing $t$ should force the graph to have fewer edges, but the bound you wrote goes in the other way.

Answer (score 2):

A graph of girth $g$ can have at most $O(n^{1+\frac1{\lfloor\frac{g-1}2\rfloor}})$ edges. This is known as the Moore bound, though now the only reference I could find online right now is this one: [Dutton and Brigham - Edges in graphs with large girth](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01787638).

Answer (score 2):

Start with a graph $G$ with average degree $d$. By deleting low-degree vertices, you can pass to a subgraph $G'$ with minimum degree $d/2$. Fixing some vertex $v_0$ in $G'$, we should have that there are $\ge (d/2-1)^i$ vertices at distance $i$ from $v_0$, for every $i\le \lfloor (g-1)/2\rfloor$ (this is proven by induction since otherwise you would create a cycle of length $\le g$, if there was some vertex at distance $i<\lfloor (g-1)/2\rfloor$ which had $\ge 2$ neighbors at distance $\le i$ to $v_0$).

Thus, we see that $|V(G')|\ge (d/2-1)^{\lfloor (g-1)/2\rfloor}$. This recovers the bound domotorp mentioned.